# Contact form get message

Tags: html, forms, contacts

There's a "contact page" in my site and I added the following html into it:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {font-family: Roboto, Roboto, sans-serif;}
<form action="mailto:pedroccoutinho@hotmail.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">

form {
}

input[type=text], select, textarea {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 19px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    resize: vertical;
}

input[type=submit] {
    background-color: #f57c00;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px 90px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #ffad42;
}

.container {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h3></h3>

<div class="container">
  <form action="/action_page.php">
    <label 
    {display:block; width:x; height:y; text-align:right;}for="fname"></label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Seu nome">
    <label for="subject"></label>
    <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Deixe sua mensagem aqui" style="height:200px"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

My issue is: if someone tryies to send a message, he'll be redirect to a 404 error page and I don't receive the message. How can I fix it and receive the message in my email?

Comment: Does `action_page.php` exist? Why is `<form action="mailto:pedroccoutinho@hotmail.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
` in your style section?

Answer (score 0):

this is only html page. to receive message in your email you have to create "action_page.php" file.
action_page.php code:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['subject']) && !empty($_POST['subject'])){
        mail("yourmail@example.com","Message from ".$_POST['firstname'],$_POST['subject']);
        echo 'success';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you didnt understood the basics.

First you have to learn more about forms: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp
Then you need to send an email a server-side language, e.g. PHP. Otherwise it will only open your mailprogram.

I made an example, but I not recommend to use THIS productive. It's to unsecure and has no vaildation, captcha, ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {font-family: Roboto, Roboto, sans-serif;}
form {
}

input[type=text], select, textarea {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 19px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    resize: vertical;
}

input[type=submit] {
    background-color: #f57c00;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px 90px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #ffad42;
}

.container {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h3></h3>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    mail('pedroccoutinho@hotmail.com', 'new contact message', $_POST['message']);
}
?>

<div class="container">
  <form action="" method="post">
    <label style="display:block; text-align:right;" for="fname"></label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Seu nome">
    <label for="message"></label>
    <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Deixe sua mensagem aqui" style="height:200px"></textarea>

    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Enviar">
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```